# How can i pass object within template in directive?

Tags: angularjs

place is a object.
 create-itinerary is directive . I open $ubiModal within a template pass create-itinerary directive and try to pass  an object place.But  in directive i got [object object].please help me.

```
$scope.showCreateItinerary = function(place) {
      var tpl = '<div create-itinerary trip-details="\'' + place + '\'"></div>';
      $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        template: tpl,
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static',
        windowClass: "signup-popup abc"
      });
};
```

Comment: do you use AngularUI?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924577/scope-issues-with-angular-ui-modal

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `resolve` param:

```
$scope.showCreateItinerary = function(place) {
    $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        template: '<div create-itinerary trip-details="place"></div>',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static',
        windowClass: "signup-popup abc",
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return {
                    place: place
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

app.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
   $scope.place = data.place;
});
```

Comment: i need place data in create-itinerary directive

Comment: @AyanSundarJana Nice, so do it.

Comment: Actually that is the problem. I can pass variable in the resolve to the modal controller. But as you can see my modal template is dynamic and it's a directive with isolated scope. So even if I pass the object to the modal controller the directive will not be able to access it. I need to pass the object to the directive somehow.

Comment: @AyanSundarJana I updated my answer. Have you tried to bind your place to an scope? Take a look at the ModelCtrl code. I also refactored your template and removed that old-school string binding and replaced it with your scope var. This should work for you.

Comment: @AyanSundarJana any feedback or suggestions?